# Microsoft Word Find/Edit Text

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a lot of documents with the following lines sprinkled through out:

```
`# Text ^p
```

Example:

```
`1 FooBar
```

They either have a paragraph end of line OR a carriage return char.

I need to remove the '`' character and make the entire line bold.

I can make the lines bold with the following:

```
Find What:
(`*)^11

Replace with \1^p
Font Bold setting...
```

However, I would like to delete the `character in the \1 placeholder in the replace with text box in the Microsoft Word Replace dialog box

to get:

**1 FooBar**

Also using the ^p or ^11 characters a line ender sometimes back fire because sometimes each line is different..

Comment: When you say each line is different, can you give some examples? How many differences can be created in that charspace?

Comment: There is an ESC code for a backspace, and one for 'right cursor' movement. Could you ESC code to the correct position and then send a backspace?

Comment: for the baktick, does find: (`)(*)^11 and replace with \2^p work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're asking about removing the `` ` `` from your replacement.

The reason that the `` ` `` appears in your replacement currently is because it's being captured (it's in the parentheses).

```
(`*)^11
```

All you have to do to is to take it out of the parentheses.

```
`(*)^11
```